# Scrabble ACSL java coding

Tags: java

So whats happening is that this code, This Code is just toooooo long. Is there any way to make this code in a simpler way? I'm a rookie and a friend asked me and he does not have any account to ask so I'm asking on mine and I am really bad at coding so please help!(I owe him)

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the word:");
    String firstLetter = input.next();
    String secondLetter = input.next();
    String thirdLetter = input.next();;
    String lastLetter = input.next();;
    int valOfFirstLetter = 0;
    int valOfSecondLetter = 0;
    int valOfThirdLetter = 0;
    int valOfLastLetter = 0;



    if (firstLetter.equals("a"))
        valOfFirstLetter = valOfFirstLetter + 1;
    else if (firstLetter.equals("e"))
        valOfFirstLetter = valOfFirstLetter + 1;
    else if (firstLetter.equals("d"))
        valOfFirstLetter = valOfFirstLetter + 2;        
    else if (firstLetter.equals("r"))
        valOfFirstLetter = valOfFirstLetter + 2;
    else if (firstLetter.equals("b"))
        valOfFirstLetter = valOfFirstLetter + 3;
    else if (firstLetter.equals("m"))
        valOfFirstLetter = valOfFirstLetter + 3;
    else if (firstLetter.equals("v"))
        valOfFirstLetter = valOfFirstLetter + 4;
    else if (firstLetter.equals("y"))
        valOfFirstLetter = valOfFirstLetter + 4;
    else if (firstLetter.equals("j"))
        valOfFirstLetter = valOfFirstLetter + 8;
    else if (firstLetter.equals("x"))
        valOfFirstLetter = valOfFirstLetter + 8;
    else
        System.out.println("NOOOOOOO");

    System.out.println(valOfFirstLetter);


    if (secondLetter.equals("a"))
        valOfSecondLetter = valOfSecondLetter + 1;
    else if (secondLetter.equals("e"))
        valOfSecondLetter = valOfSecondLetter + 1;
    else if (secondLetter.equals("d"))
        valOfSecondLetter = valOfSecondLetter + 2;      
    else if (secondLetter.equals("r"))
        valOfSecondLetter = valOfSecondLetter + 2;
    else if (secondLetter.equals("b"))
        valOfSecondLetter = valOfSecondLetter + 3;
    else if (secondLetter.equals("m"))
        valOfSecondLetter = valOfSecondLetter + 3;
    else if (secondLetter.equals("v"))
        valOfSecondLetter = valOfSecondLetter + 4;
    else if (secondLetter.equals("y"))
        valOfSecondLetter = valOfSecondLetter + 4;
    else if (secondLetter.equals("j"))
        valOfSecondLetter = valOfSecondLetter + 8;
    else if (secondLetter.equals("x"))
        valOfSecondLetter = valOfSecondLetter + 8;
    else
        System.out.println("NOOOOOOO");

    System.out.println(valOfSecondLetter);


    if (thirdLetter.equals("a"))
        valOfThirdLetter = valOfThirdLetter + 1;
    else if (thirdLetter.equals("e"))
        valOfThirdLetter = valOfThirdLetter + 1;
    else if (thirdLetter.equals("d"))
        valOfThirdLetter = valOfThirdLetter + 2;        
    else if (thirdLetter.equals("r"))
        valOfThirdLetter = valOfThirdLetter + 2;
    else if (thirdLetter.equals("b"))
        valOfThirdLetter = valOfThirdLetter + 3;
    else if (thirdLetter.equals("m"))
        valOfThirdLetter = valOfThirdLetter + 3;
    else if (thirdLetter.equals("v"))
        valOfThirdLetter = valOfThirdLetter + 4;
    else if (thirdLetter.equals("y"))
        valOfThirdLetter = valOfThirdLetter + 4;
    else if (thirdLetter.equals("j"))
        valOfThirdLetter = valOfThirdLetter + 8;
    else if (thirdLetter.equals("x"))
        valOfThirdLetter = valOfThirdLetter + 8;
    else
        System.out.println("NOOOOOOO");

    System.out.println(valOfThirdLetter);

    if (lastLetter.equals("a"))
        valOfLastLetter = valOfLastLetter + 1;
    else if (lastLetter.equals("e"))
        valOfLastLetter = valOfLastLetter + 1;
    else if (lastLetter.equals("d"))
        valOfLastLetter = valOfLastLetter + 2;      
    else if (lastLetter.equals("r"))
        valOfLastLetter = valOfLastLetter + 2;
    else if (lastLetter.equals("b"))
        valOfLastLetter = valOfLastLetter + 3;
    else if (lastLetter.equals("m"))
        valOfLastLetter = valOfLastLetter + 3;
    else if (lastLetter.equals("v"))
        valOfLastLetter = valOfLastLetter + 4;
    else if (lastLetter.equals("y"))
        valOfLastLetter = valOfLastLetter + 4;
    else if (lastLetter.equals("j"))
        valOfLastLetter = valOfLastLetter + 8;
    else if (lastLetter.equals("x"))
        valOfLastLetter = valOfLastLetter + 8;
    else
        System.out.println("NOOOOOOO");

    System.out.println(valOfSecondLetter);
    System.out.println(firstLetter + secondLetter + thirdLetter + lastLetter);
```

So what this program does is that if you type a word and only four letter word(from ACSL) only a, e = 1 Point d, r = 2 Points b, m = 3 Points v, y = 4 Points j, x = 8 Points. If I type for example j a v a with spaces, it will print our the following

```
8
1
4
1
java
```

If you type something else than those letters it will print "NOOOOOO"(I do not know why he did this)
And I do not know how I can make this into a simpler form. I'm thinking that making one string and read each letter and have it on one if else statement. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm thinking that making one string and read each letter and have it on one if else statement. Is that possible?

Absolutely.

You can read a whole word string with [nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29), split to [chars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) with [toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29), iterate the chars using a [for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), and use a [switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) to test the char's value in a slightly less repetitive way than using if/elseif.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the word:");
String word = input.nextLine();
int wordValue = 0;

for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
    int val;
    switch (c) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
        val = 1;
        break;
    case 'd':
    case 'r':
        val = 2;
        break;
    case 'b':
    case 'm':
        val = 3;
        break;
    case 'v':
    case 'y':
        val = 4;
        break;
    case 'j':
    case 'x':
        val = 8;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("NOOOOOOO");
        return;
    }

    wordValue += val;
}

System.out.println(wordValue);
```